# Node.js TypeError: JSON.parseInt is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a problem with Node.js.
I have already installed nodemoden and express.
I got an error as the title. Would anyone take a look at my code please?
I have 1 index.js file and 3 json files.
Also, I have 6 js files, 1 is meals.js below. Other 5 files are cheapmealsroute.js. largemealsroute.js and so on.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

const meals = require('./data/meals.json');
const reservations = require('./data/reservations.json');
const reviews = require('./data/reviews.json');

const mealsRouter = require('./routes/mealsroute');
const cheapMealsRouter = require('./routes/cheapmealsroute');
const largeMealsRouter = require('./routes/largemealsroute');
const randomMealRouter = require('./routes/mealroute');
const reservationsRouter = require('./routes/reservationsroute');
const reservationRouter = require('./routes/reservationroute');


app.use('/meals', mealsRouter);

app.use('/cheap-meals', cheapMealsRouter);

app.use('/large-meals', largeMealsRouter);

app.use('/random-meals', randomMealRouter);

app.use('/reservations', reservationsRouter);

app.use('/reservation', reservationRouter);

app.listen(
  port,
  () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

mealsroute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const fs = require('fs');
const meals = JSON.parseInt(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../data/meals.json'));

router.get('/', (request, response) =>
  response.send(meals)

);

module.exports = router;
```

meals.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Indian food in the summer",
    "maxNumberOfGuests": 5,
    "description": "A nice night out eating delicious indian food",
    "createdAt": "2019/12/7 14:34",
    "price": 67
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Italian food with best ingredients",
    "maxNumberOfGuests": 10,
    "description": "All ingredients from Italy freshly cooked",
    "createdAt": "2019/12/15 15:30",
    "price": 65
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Japanese food by Japanese chef",
    "maxNumberOfGuests": 4,
    "description": "A trip to Japan",
    "createdAt": "2019/11/13 10:00",
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Danish smoere brot",
    "maxNumberOfGuests": 6,
    "description": "Taste the Danish cusine",
    "createdAt": "2019/12/8 09:26",
    "price": 70
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Spanish tapas",
    "maxNumberOfGuests": 8,
    "description": "Fiesta con tus amigos",
    "createdAt": "2019/12/9 16:08",
    "price": 85
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you meant `JSON.parse`, not `parseInt`.

Comment: As the error says, `JSON.parseInt` isn't a function.  Maybe you meant `JSON.parse`

Comment: @AlexBroadwin `parseInt` on that meals.json file will produce `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that JSON.parseInt is not a function!

I don't know where you got that JSON has a parseInt function.

First parse the JSON to use the JSON as a JS Object (JSON.parse())

and then parse the integer you need with .parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

Replace`JSON.parseInt` with `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert some JSON into a JavaScript object you can use JSON.parse(myJson)

If you want to convert a string representation of an integer into a number type you can use parseInt(myStr).

I think you may be just confusing the two.